# How to remove package-dir map and use a symlink instead?

Tags: apt

I installed npm.

After that I uninstalled it by:

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get purge npm
```

Now I added a symlink via a package downloaded manually by:

lns /my_path/node

However when I run **npm** I keep getting

> bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

**EDIT:**:

npm was installed by downloading the gzip from https://nodejs.org .

I finally used

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/npm /my_path/node
```

which solved the problem as /usr/bin/ is in path.

Comment: `lns` is not a standard command. If this is a homemade alias/function/script, tell us what it does. Given that `npm` doesn't appear in the command, there's a good chance that command can't help you. How did you install npm manually? Where did you put the package?

Comment: Gilles, please check out my comment to @user454038 answer

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information I requested.

Comment: I updated my question (solved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution depends on correctly creating a sym link to `/my_path/node`, then the problem might be with your command to make a sym link, your original post says:

```
lns /my_path/node
```

Doesn't it give you an error?

The correct syntax for creating a sym link or soft link, is `ln -s target`, so applied to your example:

```
ln -s /my_path/node
```

Also remember if the directory you are trying to create a sym link in requires root priviledges, you may need to use `sudo ln -s /my_path/node`

Comment: Actually I tried both (in my case I downloaded nodejs and npm to have the latest version):
sudo ln -s ~/__installed_apps/nodejs4/bin/npm npm
... and ...
sudo ln -s ~/__installed_apps/nodejs4/bin/npm

but in both cases:

bash: node: command not found

Comment: never mind. looks like the issue was that I need to create the symlink in /usr/bin/